# Codeigniter base URL for local project?

Tags: codeigniter

Sorry for the dumb question but my websites are located in the directory: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/

I access it by going to 127.0.0.1/ in my browser. So what should I set my baseURL in the config if CodeIgniter.

Just set it to `127.0.0.1/site`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost/site`

You can also edit your hosts file and have it point to a different URL

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Look into setting up vhosts with XAMPP
http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/